# how can i make two objects belonging to the same array move independently of each other using javascript and the canvas tag?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a blackhole simulation, where all the balls that are outside of it go away from it at a given speed and those that fall on it are dragged towards the circle until they reach the center of it, where they would stop and disappear, here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>blackhole simulation escape velocity</title>
        <script>
            var canvas, ctx;
            var blackhole;
            var circle;
            var circles = new Array();
            var G = 6.67e-11, //gravitational constant
            pixel_G = G / 1e-11,
            c = 3e8, //speed of light (m/s)
            M = 12e31, // masseof the blackhole in kg (60 solar masses)
            pixel_M = M / 1e32
            Rs = (2 * G * M) / 9e16, //Schwarzchild radius 
            pixel_Rs = Rs / 1e3, // scaled radius 
            ccolor = 128;

            function update() {
                var pos, i, distance, somethingMoved = false;
                for (i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
                    pos = circles[i].position;
                    distance = Math.sqrt(((pos.x - 700) * (pos.x - 700)) + ((pos.y - 400) *   (pos.y - 400)));
                   if (distance > pixel_Rs-5 ) {
                       var delta = new Vector2D(0, 0);
                       var forceDirection = Math.atan2(pos.y - 400, pos.x - 700);
                       var evelocity = Math.sqrt((2 * pixel_G * pixel_M) / (distance * 1e-2));
                       delta.x += Math.cos(forceDirection) * evelocity;
                       delta.y += Math.sin(forceDirection) * evelocity;
                       pos.x += delta.x;
                       pos.y += delta.y;
                       somethingMoved = true;
                   } else {
                       var delta2 = new Vector2D (0,0);
                       var forceDirection2 = Math.atan2(pos.y - 400, pos.x - 700);
                       var g = (pixel_G*pixel_M)/(distance*distance*1e2);
                       delta2.x += Math.cos(forceDirection2)*g;
                       delta2.y += Math.sin(forceDirection2)*g;
                       pos.x -= delta2.x;
                       pos.y -= delta2.y;
                       somethingMoved = true;
                       circles[i].color -= 1;

                       if (pos.x == 700 && pos.y == 400){
                           somethingMoved = false;
                       };

                   }
               }
               if (somethingMoved) {
                   drawEverything();
                   requestAnimationFrame(update);
               };
           }

           function drawEverything() {
               ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
               blackhole.draw(ctx);
               for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
                   circles[i].draw(ctx);
               }
           }

           function init(event) {
               canvas = document.getElementById("space");
               ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
               blackhole = new Ball(pixel_Rs, { x: 700,
                                                y: 400 }, 0);

               for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                   var vec2D = new Vector2D(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1400), Math.floor(Math.random() * 800));
                   circle = new Ball(5, vec2D, ccolor);
                   circles.push(circle);
               }
               drawEverything();
               requestAnimationFrame(update);
           }

           function Ball(radius, position, color) {
               this.radius = radius;
               this.position = position;
               this.color = color;
           }

           Ball.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
               var c=parseInt(this.color);
               ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + c + ',' + c + ',' + c + ',1)';
               ctx.beginPath();
               ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
               ctx.closePath();
               ctx.fill();
           };

           function Vector2D(x, y) {
               this.x = x;
               this.y = y;
           }


           function onClick (){
               canvas = document.getElementById ('space');
               ctx = canvas.getContext ('2d') 
               canvas.addEventListener ("mousedown", init, false)
               blackhole = new Ball (5, {x: 700,
                                         y: 400 }, 0);
               blackhole.draw (ctx) ;                   

           }  
           window.onload = onClick;

        </script>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color:#021c36 ;
                margin: 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id = "space", width = "1400", height = "800">
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now as you can see, I created a second variable called delta2, but the problem is that it can't update the position of the circles, which in  term makes it impossible to move the circle, can someone tell me what is wrong. Also, how can I make the big black circle after a certain amount of time, i know i probably should create a timer, but i don't know how they work

Comment: You keep asking questions about how to debug this project. Perhaps try formatting your code correctly so you can see where everything logically fits then use the console to help in debugging. There's nothing explicitly restricting `delta2` from updating the position of your circles. It's just a matter of if you use that variable correctly.

Comment: but i can't tell what is wrong with `delta2`, I mean form my point of view i am not using it incorrectly, so i can't tell what is wrong with it, I am sorry but i'm just a beginner

Comment: @carretero_1. **Beginners Hint:** Based on the pattern in your questions, you seem to be stuck when adding each new feature your project. When debugging, it's often useful to create a smaller example that focuses only on the new feature. Then when you have a good understanding of the new feature it's easier to plug the new feature back into the bigger full project.

Comment: Any tip to debug a code, or at least a place to start

Comment: Open the dev tools (usually F12). Include `console.log` statements to see how your critical variables are changing. The dev tools will also show you error messages. Pull un-necessary code out of your project until you're working with just the parts that are misbehaving.

Comment: shouldn't I make some break in my code and ask it to print out the pos.x and pos.y of the circles

Comment: Sure, you can add debugging breakpoints -- instead of console.log or in addition to console.log. **Make the debugging tools your best friend!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gravity is too weak.  I put a pseudo gravity to demonstrate.

```js
var canvas, ctx;
var blackhole;
var circle;
var circles = new Array();

var bh = {
  w:500,
  h:300
};

bh.cx = Math.floor(bh.w/2);
bh.cy = Math.floor(bh.h/2)


var G = 6.67e-11, //gravitational constant
  pixel_G = G / 1e-11,
  c = 3e8, //speed of light (m/s)
  M = 12e31, // masseof the blackhole in kg (60 solar masses)
  pixel_M = M / 1e32
Rs = (2 * G * M) / 9e16, //Schwarzchild radius 
  pixel_Rs = Rs / 1e3, // scaled radius 
  ccolor = 128;

function update() {
  var pos, i, distance, somethingMoved = false;
  for (i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    pos = circles[i].position;
    distance = Math.sqrt(((pos.x - bh.cx) * (pos.x - bh.cx)) + ((pos.y - bh.cy) * (pos.y - bh.cy)));
    if (distance > pixel_Rs - 5) {
      var delta = new Vector2D(0, 0);
      var forceDirection = Math.atan2(pos.y - bh.cy, pos.x - bh.cx);
      var evelocity = Math.sqrt((2 * pixel_G * pixel_M) / (distance * 1e-2));
      delta.x += Math.cos(forceDirection) * evelocity;
      delta.y += Math.sin(forceDirection) * evelocity;
      pos.x += delta.x;
      pos.y += delta.y;
      somethingMoved = true;
    } else {
      var delta2 = new Vector2D(0, 0);
      var forceDirection2 = Math.atan2(pos.y - bh.cy, pos.x - bh.cx);
      // FIX THIS!!!
      var g = 1;//(pixel_G * pixel_M) / (distance * distance * 1e2);
      delta2.x += Math.cos(forceDirection2) * g;
      delta2.y += Math.sin(forceDirection2) * g;
      pos.x -= delta2.x;
      pos.y -= delta2.y;
      somethingMoved = true;
      circles[i].color -= 1;

      if (pos.x == bh.cx && pos.y == bh.cy) {
        somethingMoved = false;

      };

    }
  }
  if (somethingMoved) {
    drawEverything();
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  };
}



function drawEverything() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  blackhole.draw(ctx);
  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].draw(ctx);
  }
}

function init(event) {
  canvas = document.getElementById("space");
  canvas.width = bh.w;
  canvas.height = bh.h;
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  blackhole = new Ball(5, { //pixel_Rs, {
    x: bh.cx,
    y: bh.cy
  }, 0);

  for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    var vec2D = new Vector2D(Math.floor(Math.random() * bh.w), Math.floor(Math.random() * bh.h));
    circle = new Ball(5, vec2D, ccolor);
    circles.push(circle);
  }
  drawEverything();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function Ball(radius, position, color) {
  this.radius = radius;
  this.position = position;
  this.color = color;
}

Ball.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
  var c = parseInt(this.color);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + c + ',' + c + ',' + c + ',1)';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
};

function Vector2D(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}


function onClick() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('space');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", init, false)
  blackhole = new Ball(5, {
    x: bh.cx,
    y: bh.cy
  }, 0);
  blackhole.draw(ctx);

}
window.onload = onClick;
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #021c36;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="space" , width="700" , height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: but why did you change the if statement with the bh variable, what is wrong with  `if (posx==700 && posy==400)`

Comment: The resolution was too high for my monitor and I couldn't see where the origin was so I used parameters for width, height, center x, and center y for the black hole then adjust the size until I could see what's going on. I think the problem was just with the gravity and your original code there should be fine.